# Do PyQt classes inherit from object?

Tags: python, pyqt

Do PyQt classes inherit from object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> QtCore.QObject.__mro__
(<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QObject'>, <type 'sip.wrapper'>, <type 'sip.simplewrapper'>, <type 'object'>)
```

So the answer is yes (at least `QObject` does, but I assume non-descendants of `QObject` do, too).

Comment: Thanks.  I did not know about `__mro__`.

Comment: You could have used `issubclass(QtCore.QObject, object)`, but with `__mro__` you get all base classes at once.

Comment: This answer is valid for PyQt4 & 5